# Unit test for try-finally block

Tags: java, unit-testing, switch-statement, try-finally

How should I write a test for the `getUrl` method?

```
public class UrlList {
    private final String[] urls;
    private int index;
    private SecureRandom random;

    public static enum Mode {
        VALUE_1,
        VALUE_2,
        VALUE_3;
    }

    public UrlList(String... urls) {
        if (urls == null || urls.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The url list may bot be null or empty!");
        }
        this.urls = urls;
        this.index = 0;
        this.random = new SecureRandom();
    }

    public String getUrl(Mode mode) {
        switch (mode) {
        case VALUE_1:
            return urls[0];
        case VALUE_2:
            return urls[random.nextInt(urls.length)];
        case VALUE_3:
            try {
                return urls[index];
            } finally {
                index = (index + 1) % urls.length;
            }
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Unknown mode!");
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code `urls` is an array of String.

The main question is how should I test the `case VALUE_3:`?

Because for the first time test the `index = 0` but after that the value of `index` will change to something else in the `finally` block and I want to test it again with new `index` value in the same unit test class.

Comment: Firstly, if you are going to do a `try-finally` block, you need to throw an exception in your function definition.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "Because for the first time test the `nextUrlIndex = 0` but after..."

Comment: Thank u taylorcressy.But what do u think about main question ;)

Comment: To test a method you need a specification for that method: the test compares the actual behaviour of the method with the specified behaviour. So nobody can tell you how to test your method if you do not provide us with a specification for your method.

Comment: Sorry guys I've edited the code above.This is the correct code.Before the first time run the index is zero but for example if you run the method for the second or third time the index is not 0 it's changing in the finally block

Comment: suggest String[] urls = {"link1", "link2", "link3"}; and the index = 0 before the first method running.After first running when mode = VAKUE_3 it returns urls[0] but after that the value of index will change in finally blcok and if you run the method again when mode = VAKUE_3 it returns urls[1] and after second method running it returns urls[2] after third running it returns urls[0] again and so on.

Comment: The typical response in cases like this is "only test the public interface". It looks like `nextUrlIndex` is private (otherwise you could just inspect its value from the test), so either the change to `nextUrlIndex` has some effect on the public interface that you can test, or it doesn't (and is effectively implementation detail that should remain untested).

Comment: I suppose that the line `nextUrlIndex = (index + 1) % urls.length;` should be read as `index = (index + 1) % urls.length;`

Comment: @Serge Ballesta : Yes you are completely right.I edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considering creating a new instance of your class (the one encapsulating index & getUrl) , for each test method?
Thus, each test method starts freshly with index=0 ...

Comment: Hi Pelit I change the code so you can see all the class now.

Comment: I did this, but the test class can just test the "case VALUE_3: " when the index is 0.But what about when index will change and I want test it again?

Answer (score 0):

For your tests, you have to be able to set the value of the private `index` variable to (eg) :

- a value positive and less than `urls.length` to control you get `index+1`
- `url.length -1` to control you get 0
- a erroneous value (negative or greater or equal to `urls.length`) to control you get an acceptable one (after recovering from exception)

Of course index is private, but you can still have access through reflexion

```
urlList = new UrlList(...); // in test initialization
...
Field index = UrlList.class.getDeclaredField("index");
index.setAccessible(true);
index.setInt(urlList, i); // to set index
i = index.getInt(urlList); // to get index
```